# Fix leak in toilet drain pipe

Tags: toilet, drain, pvc

I have a leak in a toilet drain pipe that you can see below.

The horizontal brown line is where the leak is and it was caused by a metal support strap that was wrapped around the pipe.

Is patching the pipe with epoxy a possible long term solution?  Or should the pipe be replaced?

I definitely don't want to open up the ceiling again...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An epoxy patch is going to be a temporary fix and considering the amount of work you're going to have to go through to repair the ceiling, why not do it right?

Remove as much of the existing plumbing as you need to in order to get at "clean" ends, and then replace with new plumbing.

Comment: I would forget the epoxy part and go for the proper repair.

Comment: Agree about replacing rather than trying to patch.  But it looks like OP is going to have to cut the pipes back almost to the wall as the male parts of the joints are right against each other.  New toilet flange & pipe, 1-1/2 pipe for the sink drain, wye coupling, etc.

Comment: You have gone through the trouble of opening up the ceiling @gaefan, I agree with this advice that it's time to go with the whole ass.

Comment: You are probably right @SteveSh, but as the OP has access to the toilet presumably it shouldn't be that bad to do.

Comment: Thanks all.  Much appreciated.